# Fix integer expression expected when the variable can be empty

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create filenames with a bash script, based on title, year, season and episode number.

Only the title can be assured to be always present so I built this code:

```
title="A Title"
year=2019
source=null
resolution=null
season=null
episode=null

if [ "$year" == "null" ]; then year=""; else year=" ($year)"; fi
if [ "$source" == "null" ]; then source=""; fi
if [ "$season" == "null" ]; then season=""; fi
if [ "$season" -gt 10 ]; then season=" - S$season"; else season=" - S0$season"; fi
if [ "$episode" == "null" ]; then episode=""; fi
if [ "$episode" -gt 10 ]; then episode="E$episode"; else episode="E0$episode"; fi


touch "$title"${year:+"$year"}${season:+"$season"}${episode:+"$episode"}.file
```

This works when season or episode is not null, but when it's null it gives an error `integer expression expected`.

How to fix this error and keep the goal of this code?

Example of desired outputs:

```
A Title.file
A Title (2019).file
A Title - S01E20.file
A Title (2019) - S10E05.file
```

Comment: From your indenting, it looks like you are hoping test `season` for null, and only test for `-gt 10` if it is not null. Is this what you want? This might fix your problem (with comparing an empty string against a number).

Comment: Why not just set the variables to `""` instead of "null"?

Comment: I use a software that set the variables to null if they can't be recognized, so I set them empty to remove them from the filename.

Comment: Side note: `-gt 9` or `-ge 10` makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using bash, just just arithmetic expressions:

```
season=null
if ((season < 1)); then echo covid19
elif ((season < 2)); then echo trump2020
else echo '???'
fi

covid19
```

---

For your actual problem, you could use `printf -v` (and there are probably many other, better solutions):

```
>>> cat ./script
#! /bin/bash
if ((year)); then printf -v year ' (%d)' "$year"; else year=; fi
if ((season)); then printf -v season ' - S%02d' "$season"; else season=; fi
if ((episode)); then printf -v episode 'E%02d' "$episode"; else episode=; fi
echo "$title$year$season$episode.file"

>>> export title='A Title'
>>> ./script
A Title.file
>>> year=2019 ./script
A Title (2019).file
>>> year=2019 season=3 ./script
A Title (2019) - S03.file
>>> year=2019 season=3 episode=9 ./script
A Title (2019) - S03E09.file
>>> year=2019 season=3 episode=11 ./script
A Title (2019) - S03E11.file
>>> season=3 episode=11 ./script
A title - S03E11.file
```

Comment: @Freedo answer was made community wiki -- I don't get any rep from it and you can edit it into what actually works for you (Your Q does not say how and if `resolution` and `source` are used in the final filename).

Comment: thanks @pizdelect, your answer is the only one that worked when both season and episode are null, and when they have values...I didn't think this would be so hard! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your script is trying to test an empty string against a number.

You can avoid this by using a default value expression (`:-`) in the expansion of a variable that might be unset or set to an empty string.

For example:

```
if [ ${season:-"0"} -gt 10 ]; then BLAH...; fi
```

Since you're also testing for the word `"null"` you could also set the appropriate default value of `0` when there's a match, instead of setting it to an empty string.

Comment: Why are you quoting the `"0"` instead of the whole `"${season:-0}"`?

Comment: That's just a stylistic way to indicate the value is a string in this context.  No quoting is actually needed here unless there is some possibility of any whitespace being in the variable, but if there is then you'd still have a syntax error since the code expects only `"null"`, `""`, or a numeric value.  If you have any possibility of whitespace invading then you need more careful validation before the use of `test -gt`.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning a non-numeric value to `season`:

```
if [ "$season" == "null" ]; then season=""; fi
```

therefore in your next code, the value may be an empty string, hence the error.

You can control for the variable being numeric, which will be false if empty, before the arithmetic comparison:

```
if [[ "$season" =~ ^[0-9]+$ && "$season" -gt 10 ]]; then
  season=" - S$season"
elif [[ "$season" = "null" ]]; then
  season=" - S0"
fi
```

Comment: @Freedo Could you explain what do you mean by not working? Is an error or you don't get the expected result?

Comment: That's because there's no new assignment of `season`, therefore the value "null" remains. That's not in my code because it only test for `season` to be numeric. Then if it' not, you assign a new value.

Comment: Or better, if `season` is "null", don't use it. See my updated answer, and tell me if it works for you.

Comment: @Freedo I'm sorry to hear that, but there's nothing in your code that shows another value assigned to `season`. My code controls if `season` is numeric or null, nothing else. If it has other value, it remains untouched.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but pizdelect understood what I meant

Answer (score 0):

Combine your season if statements into a single statement. Then repeat for episode.

```
if [ "$season" == "null" ]; then
   # you could also perform some other assignment here
   season="";
elif [ "$season" -gt 10 ]; then
   season=" - S$season";
else
   season=" - S0$season";
fi
```